# Conditional time-series data aggregation

Tags: postgresql, time-series, aggregate-functions

I have a relational DB (postgres) with a table that holds time-series metrics. Each row is comprised of - `obj_id, metric_id, timestamp, value`

Let's assume I have 3 metrics of interest with codes - 1, 4 ,5. I would like to filter out all the objects that, for the same timestamp (let's assume the timestamp for all metrics are in fixed intervals), have metric 1 < 10 and (metric 4 + metric 5) < 10 with the specific timestamp that this event happened.

A more concrete example:

```
obj_id       metric_id         timestamp        value
------------------------------------------------------
1             1                83827             9
1             4                83827             2
1             5                83827             1
2             1                73261             11
2             4                73261             2
2             5                73261             5
1             1                92381             24
1             4                92381             10
1             5                92381             100
2             1                38239             7
2             4                38239             3
2             5                38239             4
```

The expected result would be:

```
obj_id     timestamp
---------------------
  1         83827
  2         38239
```

I'm trying to create an efficient query to do. That's what I had in mind in order to get the sum of 4 + 5 for the same timestamp but I'm not sure what would be the best way to glue these queries together:

```
SELECT obj_id, timestamp, sum(value) AS x
FROM metric
WHERE metric_id = 4 OR metric_id = 5
group by obj_id, timestamp
```

I'm not sure how to add to this query metric 1 (which we should query separately) and then filter out the results by `obj_id` and `timestamp`.

I thought about maybe using a self join, joining two inner selects of the same table by the timestamp.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/1f851/1)

The cast from `boolean` to `integer` yields 0 or 1

```
select obj_id, timestamp
from metric
where metric_id in (1,4,5)
group by obj_id, timestamp
having
    sum(value * (metric_id in (4,5))::integer) < 10
    and
    sum(value * (metric_id = 1)::integer) < 10
```

Comment: Absolutely brilliant and works like a charm and I can even read it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Probably this could be done better, but this felt neat to comprehend (*requires 9.4+*):

```
WITH x AS(
  SELECT 
    obj_id,
    timestamp,
    min(value) FILTER (WHERE metric_id = 1) as metric1,
    min(value) FILTER (WHERE metric_id = 4) as metric4,
    min(value) FILTER (WHERE metric_id = 5) as metric5
  FROM metric
  GROUP BY obj_id, timestamp
)
  SELECT obj_id, timestamp
  FROM x
  WHERE metric1 < 10
    AND (metric4 + metric5) < 10
```

Comment: Fails with the tuple `(2, 1, 73261, 1)`

Comment: That's because metric1 > 10... Isn't that a requirement?

Comment: FWIW, the data box in the Query gives value in the last column as 11 and not 1

Comment: I mean if that tuple is inserted into the table.